# Get favicon / tabicon from google docs website

Tags: google-docs, favicon

Have been trying to get the favicon / tabicon from docs.google.com with no luck.  Have tried the following....

```
http://docs.google.com/favicon.ico

https://docs.google.com/favicon.ico

docs.google.com/favicon.ico

https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=docs.google.com

http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://docs.google.com/docsgoogle.com.ico
```

Any other suggestions?

[Addition]

After some investigation, looks like this might not work due to the google docs sign in / authentication.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's very old, but maybe one day somebody will look for icons again.. :)

- Documents: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_document_x16.png
- Spreadsheet: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_spreadsheet_x16.png
- Forms: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_2_form_x16.png
- Drawings: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_drawing_x16.png
- Presentations: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_presentation_x16.png
- Map: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_map_x16.png
- Folder: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_folder_x16.png

Other documents icons:

- Word: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_word_x16.png
- Excel: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_excel_x16.png
- Powerpoint: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_powerpoint_x16.png
- PDF: https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_3_pdf_x16.png

Other icons:

- Keep: https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/a/911e3628e6.png
- Many other: https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_8758f7bb.png

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get onto Google Docs while at work, but you should be able to use Chrome's developer tools to look at the webpages source. They generally link the favicon in the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you find in the html source of docs.google.com, when you search for "favicon":

```
https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_4.ico
```

I checked accessibility by attempting to use that URI to edit the icon using an on-line editor - no login was necessary.

Comment: The point is to be able to get the icon using a generic URL?  Like a URL to a google document....

Comment: Something like this (does not work, just an example) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Apr2AsR8ZpbndE00ZVRMclpNbUNUbVFkaE#gid=0

Comment: The URL provided in the answer is formatted exactly like one of your examples, is a direct link to the actual google docs favicon, and is accessible without login, as you asked. You're still not clear what you mean by "generic URL", which is not a concept from the IETF standards. (The further example you've given does not, on its own, elaborate that idea.)

Comment: Ok, not sure why we are on different paths here.  If you take a google doc direct path that requires a google login, it does not seem to be able to pull the exact fave / tab icon using "normal" methods.  One can not use an HTML "scrape" to get the icon because you one is not logged in.  "generic" mean I guess "Direct to file" login.

Comment: Another thing that can be done.  1) Create a google docs spread sheet that needs a google login.  2) try and get the fav / tab icon from a "non logged in" client.

Answer (score 0):

https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/documents/images/kix-favicon7.ico

Here you go.

For reference, If you type in 'view-source:' in front of any URL, you will view its source code.

I found it in "view-source:[https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/?tgif=d"](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/?tgif=d%22)